# Hide an item after a few seconds

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I have the following JavaScript code in my head:

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $(".content").fadeOut(1500);
  },10000);

  setTimeout(function() {
    $(".content2").fadeIn(1500);
  },15000);
});
</script>
```

Then I have both divs in my body:

```html
<div class="col-sm-12">
  <div class="alert fade alert-simple alert-warning alert-dismissible text-left font__family-`montserrat font__size-16 font__weight-light brk-library-rendered rendered show" role="alert" data-brk-library="component__alert">`
    <button type="button" class="close font__size-18" data-dismiss="alert">
      <span aria-hidden="true">
        <i class="fa fa-times warning"></i>
      </span>
      <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
    </button>
    <i class="start-icon fa fa-exclamation-triangle faa-flash animated"></i>
    <strong class="font__weight-semibold">ALERT Temp
      </div>
  </div>
</div>


<!-- Alerta Static -->
<div class="content2">

  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="alert fade alert-simple alert-info alert-dismissible text-left font__family-`montserrat font__size-16 font__weight-light brk-library-rendered rendered show" role="alert" data-brk-library="component__alert">`
      <button type="button" class="close font__size-18" data-dismiss="alert">
        <span aria-hidden="true">
          <i class="fa fa-times blue-cross"></i>
        </span>
        <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
      </button>
      <i class="start-icon  fa fa-info-circle faa-shake animated"></i>
      <strong class="font__weight-semibold">ALERT Static</strong>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

As you can see, the alerts are inserted into a modal.

Could the function start to run when I open the modal instead of when I open the document?

Comment: Your HTML has missing closing tags and where is the modal?

Comment: I modified the code because I was having trouble posting it to stackoverflow, but the alerts are indise a modal

Comment: Please post code snippets of the modal too in your question. Also, are you using Bootstrap v3 or v4?

Comment: where is the element with class 'content' in your html. code